# Stata - Export F Test Results using XML_Tab

Tags: xml, export, regression, stata

I am trying to export the F-statistic and Prob > F for 2 tests of coefficients (for many regressions each). I'm using xml_tab to export regression results into excel. I've been able to store the results for the F-stat and probability [ r(p) and r(F) ] as locals, but cannot figure out a way to automate the process so that these results show up in my overall regressions in xml_tab. I understand that it is a user-written command, but was wondering if anyone has figured out a hack. I don't want to "copy-paste" because with 2 tests and so many regressions (I have more), I want to minimize human error. My code structure is below.

```
reg y x control1 control2 control3, robust plus
estimates store model_1
test control1 = control2
local p_1=r(p)
local f_1=r(F)
test control1 = control3
local p_2=r(p)
local f_2=r(F)
local x = upper(word(c(current_date),1)+word(c(current_date),2)+word(c(current_date),3))
    xml_tab author_model_1 ///
    "C:\Users\analysis_(`x').xml", ///
    replace nolabel below tstat ///
    format((S2110) (SCCB0 NCCR3 NCCR2)) ///
    keep(y x control1 control2 control3) ///
    stats(N r2 r2_a p) ///
    sheet("Analysis") ///
    title("Analysis") /// 
    cwidth(0 100, 1 80, 2 80, 3 80) ///
    cnames("Basic Regression")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "...so that these results show up in my overall regressions in xml_tab." ? Have you gone through _Creating print-ready tables in Stata_, by Lokshin and Sajaia, The Stata Journal (2008) 8, Number 3 ? It is available on the web for free.

Comment: Thank you! I have checked that out, but still don't know what I can do. I know that my tests can be stored as parameters r(p) and r(F), but don't know how I would get them exported in xml_tab, let alone differentiate between the two tests. I tried calling them as stored locals with the 'stat' part, but it didn't work. I'm referring to the 'stat' part of the function - or do you recommend something with the matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several errors with your code:

**1.** The syntax for the `xml_tab`command is:

```
xml_tab [namelist] [, options]
```

where *namelist* "is a list of stored estimations or matrices". You have `author_model_1` which does not comply with that requirement.

**2.** The .xml file to be output must be specified with the *option* `save(["]filename["])`
You do not comply with this either.

**3.** Your `keep()` option includes the dependent variable, but `keep()` is meant to handle coefficients. The dependent variable has no coefficient.

The following code works (just change the output directory)

```
clear all
set more off

sysuse auto

reg price mpg weight length, robust plus
estimates store model

local x = upper(word(c(current_date),1)+word(c(current_date),2)+word(c(current_date),3))
display "`x'"

xml_tab model, ///
    save("D:\USER\Desktop\myfile_(`x').xml") ///
    replace nolabel below tstat ///
    format((S2110) (SCCB0 NCCR3 NCCR2)) ///
    keep(mpg weight length) ///
    stats(N r2 r2_a p) ///
    sheet("Analysis") ///
    title("Analysis") /// 
    cwidth(0 100, 1 80, 2 80, 3 80) ///
    cnames("Basic Regression")
```

All this can be resolved simply looking at `help xml_tab`.

The command, according to its help file, allows only stored estimation results (using `estimates store`) and matrices.
If you want to export, for example, the results of `test` (which will *not* be saved by `estimates store`), then you can save its results to matrices and feed that into `xml_tab`.  However, some testing shows that you cannot feed both at the same time, so two calls have to be made. The first for all stored estimation results; the second for all matrices. Something like this works:

```
clear all
set more off

sysuse auto

reg price mpg weight length, robust plus
estimates store model

test mpg = weight
matrix p1 = r(p)
matrix f1 = r(F)

test mpg = length
matrix p2 = r(p)
matrix f2 = r(F)

local x = upper(word(c(current_date),1)+word(c(current_date),2)+word(c(current_date),3))

xml_tab model, save("D:\USER\Desktop\myfile_(`x').xml") replace
xml_tab p1 f1 p2 f2, save("D:\USER\Desktop\myfile_(`x').xml") append
```

The results are distributed in two sheets (when opened with MS Excel). I find the output clumsy for what you pursue, but I'm no expert using the `xml_tab` command. You might want to explore Stata built-in commands (`xml_tab` is a user-written command from SSC). To export directly to spreadsheet, try `help export excel`, `help putexcel`. For more general options try `help export`. For popular user-written commands that allow exporting results try `ssc describe estout` and `ssc describe tabout`.

Comment: Does your code output t-stat? When I specify tstat, I always get se ..